# intellij repository clone failed: Authentication failed

Tags: intellij-idea

1. versiont Control > GitHub > "Test Successufl"

[IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0N2f.jpg)

2. - Git version : 2.18.0
   - SSH ececutable: Native

[IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB160.jpg)

BUT!!

git clone fail

[IMG3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lJ9E.jpg)

I don't know why this happens any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't formatted correctly. Don't link external Images in your question, Check there is an options to add image to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are cloning via HTTP. SSH executable is not related.

Check if it works in the command line first. It could happen there is git credential.helper that somehow saved wrong credentials and git is trying to use them.

You could use SSH instead, but make sure SSH keys are registered on GitHub and, since you want to use native SSH client, the key is added to ssh-agent or does not have a passphrase, because IntelliJ is not a terminal and cannot handle interactive prompts for passphrases.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody Thanks~

I resolved it in the following way.

Step 1. Create SSH Key (in Local PC)

- My PC use Windows.
- So, I use Git Bash.

Step 2. Register GitHub

- Personal settings > SSH and GPG Keys
- Nes SSH Key > XXX_rsa.pub (This contens is Created SSH Key File in Local PC)

Step 3. In intellij, Git Clone used "Use SSH" instead of "Use HTTPS".